# SAS Proc report - ODS EXCEL column/header width

Tags: excel, sas, header, report, proc

I did a proc report and the HTML result shown in SAS gives me what i want which is :

[image]

But in EXCEL the output i get doesn't display the text horizontally it skips a line :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
ods excel file = "" 
    options(sheet_interval='none' embedded_titles='yes') ; 

ods escapechar = '^'  ;
options missing = 0 orientation=landscape center ; 

proc report data = a split = '-' 
                                style(header)={background=white borderwidth=1 bordercolor=black width=150 color=black just=c textalign=c} 
                                style(report)={borderwidth=1 bordercolor=black just=c}
                                style(column)= {borderwidth=1 bordercolor=black just=r color=black tagattr='format:###,###,###,###,###0'}
                                style(summary)= [just=c textalign=c];
;

column ( '^{style[color=red]Total}'  ('Category (before change/extension) - Performing time'
        var1 var2 var3 );

define var1 / group; 
define var2 / analysis sum ; 
define var3 / analysis sum ; 

run ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the ods excel option with flow for tables? I had the same issue and it helped with mine; from the [SAS support document](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/using-sas-ods-create-excel-worksheets.pdf):

> The ODS Excel destination is a measured destination that uses an
> algorithm to determine when text should wrap within a cell. This
> wrapping algorithm creates a best fit for columns so that they are not
> overly wide. When text does wrap within a cell, a
> carriage-return/line-feed character (CRLF) is added where the line
> break occurs.
>
> ...the most dynamic method is to use the FLOW= tagset option.   The
> fourth maintenance release for SAS® 9.4 (TS1M4) introduces the ODS
> Excel destination's FLOW= suboption. When this option is specified,
> the Excel destination does not insert newline characters to force the
> text to wrap in the part of the output that is specified as an
> argument in the option. The FLOW= option  also turns on the Wrap Text
> feature in Excel so that Excel will wrap the text to the column width.
>
> Value Area Effected  TABLES Enables flow of column headings, row
> headings, and data cells.  HEADERS Enables flow for headings only.
> ROWHEADERS Enables flow for row headings.  DATA Enables flow for data
> cells only.
>
> The following example demonstrates the use of the ODS Excel
> destination along with the TITLE_FOONTNOTE_BREAK=,
> ABSOLUTE_COLUMN_WIDTH=, and FLOW= options.

```
Example 1. 
ods excel file="c:\temp1.xlsx" options(embedded_titles="Yes" 
                                        title_footnote_nobreak="yes" 
                                        flow="header,data" 
                                        absolute_column_width="75px,50px, 
                                        70px,50px,100px,125px,300px"); 
                                        ods text="Confidential Report";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are "supposed" to do this is like this:

```
{style[tagattr="wrap:no"]Category...
```

However, this doesn't really work properly for me when I test it - it does remove the wrap, but it also removes the spaces, and it doesn't seem to work properly with the break separator (the hyphen).

Comment: It seems like it worked mostly. I added the options tagattr="wrap:no" vjust=m asis=on to style(header)

Comment: Sounds like that might be a good answer on its own, as you figured out the other issues!